# How to run my docker images on kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a custom docker image that can run on docker like below:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/peter/mgr-test# docker images
REPOSITORY                                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
850473919045.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/peter-demo-ecr    latest              3df81b4fa7e8        3 days ago          601 MB
centos7/mgr                                                    v1                  3df81b4fa7e8        3 days ago          601 MB
```

To run docker container:

```
docker run --privileged -idt \
    -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup \
    --name mgr5 \
    -h abcloud-mgr5.byoc.acer.com \
    centos7/mgr:v1 /usr/sbin/init
```

To login docker container:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/peter/mgr-test# docker exec -it 180d13e5acba bash
Configuring ipa-client, please wait....
[root@abcloud-mgr1 /]#
```

How can I use `kubectl run` to my docker image?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run docker image with kubectl using following command

> kubectl run --image=image_name container_name

Similarly you will also find `kubectl exec` command to run in interactive mode.
For detailed information visit [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/) documentation.